# Reacting to force in iOS Game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

please forgive me I am new to iOS development. I have started to make a basic game and would like to use 3D touch to control it. Basically, depending on how much force is applied to the screen will control what my player does: more force will lift the player up, less force will allow the player to fall. 
My questions are:

Is there enough scope within the minimum and maximum allowed force values to control such a game?

What code would be required in order to measure the force value and react accordingly to it? I have looked on Apple's developer site and found that `force` is within the `UITouch` class, and have noticed the code

```
var force: CGFloat { get }
```

but I am unsure how to adapt this for my own use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITouch` has to values that you could use for your purpose: `force` gives you the actual force that the user pressed. `maximumPossibleForce` is a constant of the highest possible force. You can use those two values to get a relative force (in relation to the maximum):

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first where traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
        let relativeForce = touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
    }
}
```

You have to try out yourself if this gives you enough range for your game.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. Atleast I know that I am on the right track now! I tried entering this statement earlier on after finding it on a tutorial site, but I keep getting an error - use of unresolved identifier "traitCollection". I am unsure as to what this refers to.

Comment: Make sure that you add this method to a class that implements the `UITraitCollection` protocol. Like `UIView` or `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hi I have added this method to the UIView class, but now I get an error on  `let relativeForce` saying relativeForce was never used. Sorry to keep asking basic questions!

Comment: No problem! You are getting this warning because you are not doing anything with `relativeForce`. It will go away once you start doing something with that value.

Comment: Ahh this makes sense! Many thanks for your reply, and apologies once again for taking up your time!

Comment: Hi, On my GameScene.swift I have a class of `class GameScene: SKScene`. In order for me to implement the `UITraitCollection` I have had to call the class `class ForceTouch: UIView {` within GameScene.swift (not sure if this is correct). This seems to make all the errors disappear... except when i try to extract and work with `playerFlight` (my force value) outside of `class ForceTouch` it presents me with an error "use of unresolved identifier". I have come to the conclusion that I cannot use `playerFlight` within `class GameScene`. is there any way around this?

Comment: `class ForceTouch: UIView {
    
    
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first where traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
            
            let relativeForce = touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
            let forceMultiplier: CGFloat = 100
            let playerFlight = CGFloat(relativeForce) * CGFloat(forceMultiplier)
            var playerVelocity = CGPoint.zero
            func flyPlayer() {
                playerVelocity = CGPoint(x: 0, y: playerFlight)`